# gem version dilemma with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I want to use ebayapi gem (https://github.com/codyfauser/ebay) with my rails 3.1 application.
If I add the gem in the Gemfile, rails doesn't run.

```
/Users/ssk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/money-1.7.1/lib/support/cattr_accessor.rb:7:in `cattr_reader': undefined method `id2name' for {:instance_writer=>true}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

I removed the ebayapi gem and tried "require 'ebay'" but it said that "no such file to load".

Ebayapi gem works only with money 1.7.1 and I think that conflicts with rails 3.1 (maybe 3.0 as well).

Is there a way to workaround?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

If it's truly incompatible, and you're up to fixing it yourself, then fork the projects in question on github, and update your `Gemfile` to point to your git repo (or even a local path to make editing a lot easier).

Here's an example:

```
gem 'money', :path => "~/dev/ruby/gems/money"

# or

gem 'money', :git => "git://github.com/my_account/money.git"
```

Once you've fixed it, send a pull request to the original project so they can include the fix.